# Pass a variable from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pass the variable from a JavaScript function - selected text  - to the same page using php post method:

```
if (isset($_POST['u_name']))
{
    echo $_POST['u_name'] . '</p>';
}
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var var1 = 0; var range = window.getSelection ();";
    echo "function gst () { var range = window.getSelection (); alert (range.toString ()); var1 = range.toString ();}";
    echo "document.write('<form method=\'post\'>');";
    echo "document.write('<p>selected area:<br />');";
    echo "document.write('<button onclick=\'gst ()\'  type=\'submit\' name=\'u_name\' value = \'' + var1 + ' \' />Button</button>');";
    echo "document.write('</form>');";
    echo "alert (interesting);";
    echo "</script>";
```

after pressing the button the selected page text is correct: it is checked with alert (range.toString ()) , however, the initial value of var1 variable - 0 is posted.
What could cause it and how one can pass the value, obtained from the javascript function through post method ?

Anton

Comment: Do you want pass the $_POST['u_name']  value as initial for JavaScript 'var1'?

Comment: not exactly: I want to select text and set var1 in javascript and then pass this variable through post request to php in the same script, so that this text was shown at the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you set `value` attribute on the page load.

You can change it dynamically on button click. Replace one of your rows to:

```
echo "document.write('<button onclick=\"this.setAttribute(\'value\', var1); gst()\"  type=\'submit\' name=\'u_name\' value = \'' + var1 + ' \' />Button</button>');";
```

Note `this.setAttribute`.

Comment: it seems that gst() isn't called at all in this case : even the alert box is not shown

Comment: you were close: had to set eventlistener, and change the value there:
echo "document.write('<button id=\"t\"   type=\'submit\' name=\'u_name\'  />Button</button>');";
echo "var el = document.getElementById(\"t\"); ";
echo "document.getElementById(\"t\").addEventListener(\"click\", function(){gst (); el.value=var1;});";

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass JavaScript variables to PHP, you'll have to use an Ajax request.

PHP is server sided, whereas JavaScript is client sided. This means that all PHP code is done before any JavaScript is even triggered. You can manipulate JavaScript with PHP, but if you want to manipulate PHP with JavaScript, use an [Ajax call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).